# How to recognise rows if they exist with pdo

Tags: php, pdo

I have goot the following function:

```
public function search_exists($word){
   $word=trim($word);
   $query="SELECT * FROM `search` WHERE `word`=$word";
   echo $query;
   $st=$this->pdo->query($query);
   if($st->fetch()){

      return true;
   }
   return false;
```

}

I want to check whether rows exist.. problem is that I am new to pdo..and It returns false.. when I know that there is a row..hmm

**UPDATE**:

About sql_injection:

I use this:

```
  $word=$pdo->quote($_GET['search']);
```

I thought to withdraw data from the query like this:

```
public function search_exists($word){
       $word=trim($word);
       $query="SELECT search_id FROM `search` WHERE `word`=$word";
       echo $query;
       $st=$this->pdo->query($query);
       while($row=$st->fetch()){

          return $row['search_id'];
       }
       return false;
   }
```

problem..that even the above query doesnt work

Comment: 1. Use `COUNT(*)` instead, and check if it is `> 0` 2. Use prepared statements

Comment: to tell you the truth,, i want to withdraw a few rows from it..

Comment: "About sql_injection:

I use this:" --- it's not good solution. Your method shouldn't rely that the caller sanitizes data properly. Don't trust to no one, even to yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all : use prepared statement to bind a parameter :

```
public function search_exists($word){
  $word=trim($word);
  $query="SELECT * FROM `search` WHERE `word`=:word";
  echo $query;
  $st=$this->pdo->prepare($query);
  $st->bindValue('word',$word);
  $st->execute();
  if($st->fetch()){

   return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

now your query has no problem with quoting AND there is no possibility of sql injection.

Then, an other possibility is to use the count statement, it is strictly equivalent

```
public function search_exists($word){
  $word=trim($word);
  $query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `search` WHERE `word`=:word";
  echo $query;
  $st=$this->pdo->prepare($query);
  return $st->fetchColumn() > 0;
```

}

## About your update

If you want to get the data :

```
 public function search_exists($word){
      $word=trim($word);
      $query="SELECT * FROM `search` WHERE `word`=:word";
      echo $query;
      $st=$this->pdo->prepare($query);
      $st->bindValue('word',$word);
      $st->execute();
      $result = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if(isset($result['id_result'])){

       return result['id_result'];
      }
      return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If `word` is a string type, you might try surrounding it with quotes:

```
$query="SELECT search_id FROM `search` WHERE `word` = '$word'";
```

As mentioned though, you should be [binding the parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), then you wouldn't be running into this issue, as it would add the quotes for you when necessary. It would protect you better from Sql Injection.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php), instead of calling `fetch()`, try just iterating through `$st`:

```
foreach($st as $row) {
  echo $row['search_id'];
}
```

Comment: yea..but beforehand.. i do this:   $word=$pdo->quote($_GET['search']);

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public function search_exists($word){

$word=trim($word);

$query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `search` WHERE `word`=$word";

echo $query;

$st=$this->pdo->query($query);

if($st->fetchColumn()>0){
   return true;
}

return false;
```

}

Comment: I would use prepared statements.